# Which installed software packages use the most disk space on Debian?

Tags: apt, disk-usage

Disk space on my root partition is running low, so I want to delete some applications from the system. How can I see which software packages use the most disk space? Is it possible to view that from `aptitude`?

I know about generic disk space analyzers like `df` or `baobab`, but I need solutions for installed applications.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/62290/how-do-i-list-installed-software-with-the-installed-size

Comment: You you have space on other partition .e.g. `/home`. There may be other solutions.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The easiest way is to run `wajig large`. The package should be an `apt install`-away.

Here's two links for other ways of doing it:

- [List your largest installed packages (on Debian/Ubuntu)](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3842/list-your-largest-installed-packages-on-debianubuntu)
- [LIst all installed packages in size order](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=599424)

Also remember that the installed size is just part of the space taken up by packages.  The compressed version is probably still in the cache, and that takes up some space too. You can remove those with `apt-get clean`.

Comment: The command to empty the package cache is `apt-get clean`. “clears out the local repository of retrieved package files” – man apt-get

Comment: What does "config-files" vs "installed" mean in wajig output? Their documentation doesn't quite explain this.

Comment: @Fizz I suspect "config-files" means that the package has been uninstalled, but has not been purged (apt-get purge) so the config files are still there in case the package is reinstalled at a later time.

Answer (score 208):

The easiest way (without installing extra packages) is:

```
dpkg-query -Wf '${Installed-Size}\t${Package}\n' | sort -n
```

which displays packages in *estimated* size order, in kilobytes, largest package last.

Unfortunately on at least some systems, this list includes packages that have been removed but not purged. All such packages can be purged by running:

```
dpkg --list |grep "^rc" | cut -d " " -f 3 | xargs sudo dpkg --purge
```

Or if you don't want to purge uninstalled packages you can use this variant to filter out the packages which aren't in the 'installed' state from the list:

```
dpkg-query -Wf '${db:Status-Status} ${Installed-Size}\t${Package}\n' | sed -ne 's/^installed //p'|sort -n
```

Comment: "Installed-size" is a preempted estimate of how much space the installed package would need. It's not the actual size, I'm afraid.

Comment: FWIW, if you want the largest packages first, use `sort -nr` instead of `sort -n`.

Comment: @AndreHolzner I would recommend `sort -nr | head`

Answer (score 31):

Since you want to `see which [installed] software packages use the most disk space[,] from aptitude` ... of course you can use `aptitude`! via either its CLI or {interactive, TUI, non-CLI} awesomeness. Let's discuss the CLI first, then the TUI. Either way, you just need to know the

- commandline options to use. Following text uses long options (for ease of searching documentation), but of course short options are also available.
- commandline argument to use
- output format string to use

The most basic commandline to show which installed software packages use the most disk space is probably

```
aptitude search --sort '~installsize' --display-format '%p %I' '~i' | head
```

so let's break that down:

- `--sort` is package sort order, and `~installsize` specifies a [package sort policy](https://aptitude.alioth.debian.org/doc/en/ch02s05s01.html#secSortingPolicy).
- `installsize` means 'sort on (estimated) installed size', and the preceding `~` means sort descending (since default for all sort policies is ascending).
- `--display-format` changes the `<you guessed :->`. The [format string](https://aptitude.alioth.debian.org/doc/en/ch02s05s01.html#secDisplayFormat) `'%p %I'` tells `aptitude` to output package name, then installed size.
- `'~i'` tells `aptitude` to search only installed packages.
- ... and, unless you have **very** few installed packages (my kinda-generic Debian workstation has over 2400), you want to pipe to `head` or `less` or a file, or maybe just `wc -l` to see how many lines `aptitude` will be returning.

You might also want to

1. specify the line width (in characters) for `aptitude` to use when displaying, with `--width <your desired integer value/>` . `aptitude` will default to what it believes to be your terminal width, but sometimes it guesses wrong, and sometimes you wanna write to a file, etc.
2. display more information in your format string, or change field widths. E.g., my enhanced format string `'%30p %I %r %60d'` displays

   - `%30p` : package name in field width=30 char
   - `%I`   : estimated install size
   - `%r`   : 'reverse depends count': approximate number of other installed packages which depend upon this package
   - `%60d` : package's short description in field width=60 char

Note that, if you don't see changes in your output field, you probably need to set `--width`.

... and you can also do this sort of thing in the {interactive, TUI} `aptitude`. E.g., to set display format preference,

- click or navigate to Options->Preference
- scroll to *The display format for package views*
- add `%I` to the current value in the position desired

To limit search to installed packages in the interactive `aptitude`,

- press <kbd>l</kbd> (lowercase `L`)
- enter `~i` in the dialog

To sort on installed size in the interactive `aptitude`,

- press <kbd>Shift-S</kbd> (uppercase `S`)
- enter `installsize` in the dialog

References:

- for `aptitude` package search patterns, see https://aptitude.alioth.debian.org/doc/en/ch02s04s05.html#tableSearchTermQuickGuide
- for `aptitude` package sort policies, see https://aptitude.alioth.debian.org/doc/en/ch02s05s01.html#secSortingPolicy
- for `aptitude` output display format, see https://aptitude.alioth.debian.org/doc/en/ch02s05s01.html#secDisplayFormat

Comment: Not sure if there is a way to do it, but it'd be nice to always print size in kB, that'd make it much easier to sort or otherwise postprocess.

Comment: @derobert was looking how I could control the white space in the output of aptitude, also, apparently there's no way to change the output of size.

Comment: @Braiam yes, what is the total amount of space gained if I remove `*texlive*`?

Comment: @terdon mm... wouldn't `aptitude -s remove '?and(texlive,~i)'` be enough? Also, you can add a user-tag to certain package so you can manipulate them as whole (like the tasks).

Answer (score 17):

In case you don't want to install wajig. I imagine everybody has debian-goodies installed:

```
dpigs              - Show which installed packages occupy the most space
```

Comment: wajig requires python 3 which is another 40mb. debian-goodies requires python 2.6+ so is 700kb additional. This or JosephH's answer are the best!

Comment: I noticed that `dpigs` actually has the same result as `dpkg-query -Wf '${Installed-Size}\t${Package}\n' | sort -nr | head`, which is the top ten of installed packages that occupy the most space. Still, `dpigs` is simple and short.

Answer (score 12):

First of all, use a tool like [`baobab`](http://www.marzocca.net/linux/baobab/) (`sudo apt-get install baobab`) to show you *where* that space is being used:

[image]

That will give you a nice graphical overview and help you narrow down what is taking up your space. You can also get this information on the command line using `du`:

```
$ sudo du -ch /
```

Pass this through `sort` (assuming GNU `sort`, whicih should be the case in Debian) to sort by directory size:

```
$ sudo du -ch / | sort -h
```

---

As a next step, you can see how much space a particular package is using with this command:

```
$ sudo apt-get --assume-no --purge remove "PACKAGE_NAME" | grep "be freed" | 
   awk '{print $4, $5}'
```

On my system, for example, removing all `texlive` packages will free 1,502 MB:

```
$ sudo apt-get --assume-no --purge remove "texlive*" | grep "be freed" | 
   awk '{print $4, $5}' 
1,502 MB
```

Finally, you can get this information for *all* installed packages with this command:

```
$ for i in $(dpkg -l | awk '($1=="ii"){print $2}'); do  
    echo -e "$i\t"$(sudo apt-get --assume-no --purge remove "$i" | 
                    grep "be freed" | awk '{print $4, $5}'); 
  done
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [wajig](http://packages.qa.debian.org/w/wajig.html) package, and the command

```
wajig large
```

The help explains what this does.

```
wajig large -h

usage: wajig large [-h]

List size of all large (>10MB) installed packages
```

See also the [project page](http://www.togaware.com/wajig/).

Answer (score 5):

to add to other answers, if you like command line you can use good old `durep`

```
# durep -td 1 /etc                         # or -td 2
[ /etc   319.4K (60 files, 43 dirs) ]
  90.2K [########                      ]  28.26% apache2/
  27.5K [##                            ]   8.62% apt/
  23.7K [##                            ]   7.43% mime.types
  19.7K [#                             ]   6.18% cron.daily/
  18.7K [#                             ]   5.87% services
  18.0K [#                             ]   5.64% security/
  14.7K [#                             ]   4.61% init.d/
  13.2K [#                             ]   4.13% ssl/
  11.1K [#                             ]   3.48% ld.so.cache
   9.0K [                              ]   2.81% locale.gen
   7.8K [                              ]   2.43% pam.d/
   4.5K [                              ]   1.42% default/
   4.3K [                              ]   1.35% skel/
   2.9K [                              ]   0.92% locale.alias
```

You can probably free up space using `localepurge`

```
# dpkg-reconfigure localepurge
# localepurge
localepurge: Disk space freed in /usr/share/locale: 26160 KiB
localepurge: Disk space freed in /usr/share/man: 1304 KiB

Total disk space freed by localepurge: 27464 KiB
```

Finally, you can probably get rid of icons and fonts that sometimes can take a lot of space. See details at this website

https://ownyourbits.com/2017/02/18/squeeze-disk-space-on-a-debian-system/

(examples extracted from ownyourbits)

Comment: `dpkg-reconfigure localepurge` complains about `localepurge` package not being available.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a few more tools to the list, I've always used `debfoster` and `deborphan` on my systems. They're most useful for hunting old dependencies that are hanging around after upgrades.

`apt-get autoremove` is great, but doesn't get everything and since it follows the installation marks, it doesn't quite always know what you wish to keep. Using `apt-mark` lets you direct it to some extent, though.

Check also: https://wiki.debian.org/ReduceDebian

Answer (score 1):

While this is a nice collection of tools, to which I'd add the KDE / QT Filelight, which is similar to other gui disk space usage tools, it's not the literal answer to the topic title.

If you take the question of this thread literally, that is, what are the largest packages in your system, as a rule, they are:

The libreoffice suite of packages, which isn't a single package, but it's really big.

The linux kernel and associated header packages comes I think second, and if you have multiple kernels installed, which most systems tend to have, each one is around I think 135 mB disk space, roughly, gets bigger every year, but it's about that big. If you use non free video drivers there would be the associated driver packages/files as well. Note that as with libreoffice, each kernel actually can actually be made up of 2 or 3 packages, the image, header, and driver packages, so a literal per package size count isn't actually that accurate except to get a crude sense.

After those, there aren't a huge number of massive packages in Debian's package pool that I'm aware of.

I find that once the root partition starts getting big enough to where you start wondering how to get rid of packages to shrink it, it's generally time to move/resize to a bigger root partition.

apt-get clean of course is the first thing to run, to get rid of all the cached .deb files, but once you remove that, and all but say 2 kernels, if you're still stuck with not enough room, it's more practical to increase the partition size since the cleanups etc just are red flags you are running close to out of root partition space, which can be a real problem if apt doesn't have enough room in /var to actually download and extract packages for an upgrade. Cleaning out by purge actions leftover config files from removed packages won't do  you any good at all in terms of regaining disk space since they are tiny, but it is nice to do now and then just to clean up cruft, but it shouldn't be mistaken for actually regaining any meaningful disk space.

apt-get auto-remove isn't bad either, but be aware that it's sometimes wrong about the package being removed, so you want to check that list carefully before you let apt remove the stuff. Technically it's better to purge that list, that way you get rid of the config files as well at the same time, remove or auto-remove will I believe leave them in place.

Comment: To make your root partition explode, simply install texlive. That should do it :) The debian (bullseye) default partitioning scheme is to blame, IMHO, recommending a ludicrously small amount of space for the root partition (23G in my case on a 1TB disk). If they defaulted to like 50GB or 100GB, most use cases would be covered.