# How to install apt packages to SD card

Tags: debian, beagleboneblack

i have beaglebone black wireless which have 4gb of its memory , after flashing debian 9.9 os on it am left with 200 mb free space. so i wonder how can i change apt package installer path so that whenever i install apt package its installed on SD card , i have done this earlier using some guide on stackoverflow i think but am not able to find it again :( which is bad so wondering if anyone can help with it so that apt packages installed to external sd card of beaglebone

Comment: 1) First clean up! Check https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40442/which-installed-software-packages-use-the-most-disk-space-on-debian and see which large packages you can remove. 2)  Use the SDcard for moving large, but less system-critical directories like `/var/cache` and `/usr/local/share` to the SDcard and mount that directories to their correct place via `/etc/fstab`. This way `apt` can work normally without caring for special paths, and your system will not die on SDcard problems.

Comment: thanks , i will try that